# Are Google App Engine Instances Multi-AZ by default?

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform

I have a GAE application with automatic scaling enabled in the configuration within a region in GCP.

I wanted to know if this deployment is HA(Highly Available) by default?
Does GAE fail across multiple-zones or multi-AZ by default within a region or does this have to be explicitly setup?

If it is by default, how do I verify that my application does indeed failover to multiple zones is case of failure/outage in a region?

GAE doc says -
"App Engine is regional, which means the infrastructure that runs your apps is located in a specific region, and Google manages it so that it is available redundantly across all of the zones within that region." - https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/locations

Would like to verify the above explicitly by checking through console or CLI.

Comment: Maybe you can figure this out from the IP address?  I'm pretty sure google publishes IP address ranges for regions but I don't know about zones.

Answer (score 1):

As you saw in the documentation, App Engine is a regional service, meaning it will failover to another zone in the region, if the original zone goes down.  This is part of the underlying infrastructure, and does not require any configuration or management from the user, but is also not visible to the user, either.

Answer (score -1):

Just to add some inputs, if high availability is critical to your application, you can use [Compute Engine](https://cloud.google.com/compute/) as it gives you the option to create an instance in any region you want. You can then use a [Load Balancer](https://cloud.google.com/load-balancing/) to serve the traffic and scale the instances as you want. Here is some [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/tutorials/high-availability-load-balancing) that you can refer to.